# How do I fix this error: constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm getting this error:
ElectricCar.java: Line 6: constructor Car in class Car cannot be applied to given types;

I'm not sure why I'm getting this because the ElectricCar constructor isn't referencing the superclass (other than the class extending it). How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

**CarTester.java:**

```
    public class CarTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a Car object
        Car a = new Car("Car1", "1000");
        // Print out the model
        System.out.println(a.getModel());
        
        System.out.println(a.getMPG());
        // Print out the MPG
        
        // Print the object
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        
        // Create an ElectricCar object
        ElectricCar b = new ElectricCar("Car2");
        
        // Print out the model
        System.out.println(b.getModel());
        // Print out the MPG
        System.out.println(b.getMPG());
        // Print the object
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
}
```

**ElectricCar.java:** (Line 6 of this class is getting the error)

```
public class ElectricCar extends Car {

private String model;
// Complete the constructor

public ElectricCar(String model){
    this.model = model;
}

public String getModel()
{
    return model;
}

@Override
public String getMPG()
{
    return "Electric cars do not calculate MPG.";
}

// Override the getMPG here.
// It should return: "Electric cars do not calculate MPG.

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return model + " is an electric car.";
}
// Override the toString() here.
// (model) is an  electric car.
```

}

**Car.java:**

```
public class Car {

//This code is complete
private String model;
private String mpg;

public Car(String model, String mpg){
    this.model = model;
    this.mpg = mpg;
}

public String getModel(){
    return model;
}

public String getMPG(){
    return mpg;
}

public String toString(){
    return model + " gets " + mpg + " mpg.";
}
```

}

Comment: In ElectricCar you need to specifically call the superclass' constructor. This should be the first line in the constructor, and should be ``super(name, 0);``

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't declare a `model` field in `ElectricCar` since it already has a field of that name from `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add in class Car constructor with no arguments(empty).That should solve the problem